# Zabbix : Item already exists, inherited from another template

Tags: zabbix

We apply zabbix template to the server using the "Import" option available in UI. Say, template A is linked with another template B (A -> B) and the templates are applied to the zabbix server.

In the next version/release :

1. Template A is no longer associated with B
2. Template A is linked with a new template C (A -> C)
3. Items from B has been moved to C (C is a superset of B).

Now, if I try to import the latest version of the template (A -> C) on top of older version (A -> B) from the "import" option in UI, I get the following error :

```
Item "<Item_Key>" already exists on "<Template_Name>", inherited from another template.
```

But, as you can understand, in the latest version of the template (A -> C), template B is no longer there and hence there is no question of conflict between items in B and C.

Zabbix Version : 2.4.7

**Update :** Detailed steps to reproduce along with the sample templates are available [here](https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?p=176701#post176701).

Comment: Did you select the checkbox in the "Delete missing" column?

Comment: Even if I don't select "Delete Missing" column, it's happening.

Comment: @asaveljevs, am I doing something wrong or is this a valid issue (bug) for zabbix? It will be good to know your opinion.

Comment: It may be better to discuss this on Zabbix forums (https://www.zabbix.com/forum/), where it would be possible for you to attach the necessary XML files to reproduce the problem. Then we can investigate whether this is a bug or not.

Comment: I have already raised this issue in Zabbix forum : https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=52067. Do you want me to provide, sample template?

Comment: OK. Done. The sample templates have been attached in the zabbix forum :https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?p=176701#post176701

Comment: Thanks, looks like a bug indeed. Please report it on our tracker.

Comment: Thank you. Please mention that as an answer. I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Zabbix and we thank you for reporting it at [ZBX-10254](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-10254).